# Port Selection and Batch Runner Application

Tags: c#, random

I have never written an application, so I will post the entirety of the code (80 lines). (I come from a background of putting together scripts.)

My goal is to load, or create a list of "used" ports, choose a number within a range that isn't on the list, and if the amount of tries to reach an unused port reaches 129, to run a windows batch file.

This also would turn the chosen port into a .cmd

(some of this is an amalgamation of sources from SO)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
namespace randomport
{
    class Core
    {
        public const int 
            minval = 8001,
            maxval = 8128;
        public static int[] usedPorts = new int[]{};
        public static int 
            chosenPort = 0,
            tries = 0,
            timeout = 10;
        public static bool read = false;
        public static void Main()
        {
            if(!read)
            {
                Read();
                read = true;
            }
            RandGen();
        }
        public static void RandGen()
        {
            Process proc = null;
            Random rand = new Random();
            if(tries < 129) chosenPort = rand.Next(minval, maxval);
            else
            {
                proc.StartInfo.FileName                 = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\sendservfull.bat";
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError    = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput   = true;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute          = false;

                proc.Start();

                proc.WaitForExit
                    (
                        (timeout <= 0)
                        ? int.MaxValue : timeout * 100 * 60
                    );
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < usedPorts.Length; i++)
            {
                if(chosenPort != usedPorts[i])
                {
                    Write();
                //  Application.Exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    tries += 1;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\activeports.txt")) 
            {
                string[] values = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(';');
                for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    int.TryParse(values[i], out usedPorts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Write()
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\activeports.txt", "set port="+chosenPort+";");
            File.Move(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\activeports.txt", Path.ChangeExtension(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TerrariaServer\filebin\activeports.txt", ".cmd"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have a little work to do on the final export (like removing ";").

The script compiles, but does not run as intended. Something is definitely wrong, but I am unaware of it. If it is something obvious, I guess that would be handy, otherwise if it is simply format and so on, I clearly need to do a little more studying.

Comment: What's your question? Clearly, your code will crash, but what's the question?

Comment: I guess I should do more Google search on writing functioning code -- my question is very vague D:

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you not use Google to learn how to write code. Go read a book. Also, FYI, that's not a script - it's a program. There's a big difference, which you have not yet learned. You will find it difficult to write a decent program using the same thought process you would have used to create a script.

Comment: I see, so it is not as simple as having something reference hooks. My knowledge is futile, at least until I can compile a functioning program. :)

Comment: I didn't mean a reference book - I meant a book to teach you how to develop a program. And compiling a program won't help you if what you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: Unfortunately we need something pretty soon, but I'll see about another alternative with what I know, and will write a functioning application after some reading.

Comment: Have you looked into PowerShell? See "[Scripting with PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)". PowerShell is a command line and scripting tool that is powerful enough to do this sort of thing. And it is _already_ a scripting tool.

Comment: While I like powershell, I found this easier to integrate into a set of batch files, since I'm still unfamiliar with the shell. After solving the writing multiple lines to a file issue, this will be ok (recompiled with VS Express, solving the lack of dll references). May use the powershell for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled using visual studio 2008 express this time, and cleaned it up. It was hard to tell which were the issues without a debugger, such as a missing parenthesis.

File writing, compiling, and crashing solved..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
namespace randomport
{
    class Core
    {
        public static int[] usedPorts = new int[] { };
        public static int
            minval = 8001,
            maxval = 8129,
            chosenPort = 0,
            timeout = 10,
            temp = 1024;
        public static bool read = false;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
            if (!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin"));
                //  using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt"))) { }
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\chosenport.cmd")))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin"));
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\chosenport.cmd"))) { }
            }
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                if (args[0] == "-noread")
                {
                }
                else if (args[0] == "-read" || args[0] == "-default")
                {
                    if (!read)
                    {
                        Read();
                        read = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!read)
                {
                    Read();
                    read = true;
                }
            }
            if (args.Length >= 3)
            {
                if (args[1] != "-default" || args[1] != "0")
                {
                    int.TryParse(args[1], out temp);
                    if (temp > 1024 && temp < 65535)
                    {
                        minval = temp;
                    }
                }
                if (args[2] != "-default" || args[2] != "0")
                {
                    int.TryParse(args[2], out temp);
                    if (temp > 1024 && temp < 65535)
                    {
                        maxval = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            RandGen();
        }
        public static void RandGen()
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
            Random rand = new Random();
            chosenPort = rand.Next(minval, maxval);
            for (int i = 0; i < usedPorts.Length; i++)
            {
                if (chosenPort != usedPorts[i])
                {
                    Write();
                }
                else return;
            }
        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
            if (!File.Exists(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt")))
            {
                File.Create(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt"));
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt")))
            {
                string[] values = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(';');
                usedPorts = new int[values.Length];//Initialize the array with the same length as values
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    int.TryParse(values[i], out usedPorts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Write()
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
            File.AppendAllLines(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\activeports.txt"), new string[] { chosenPort + ";" });
            using (StreamWriter sw2 = File.CreateText(String.Concat(path, "\\desktop\\TerrariaServer\\filebin\\chosenport.cmd")))
            {
                sw2.WriteLine("set port=" + chosenPort);
            }
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```